# Swift swipe navigation adjusting view controller size

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, viewcontroller

I'm trying to make a swipe navigation with view controllers instead of xib files using this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU

I've managed to replace the xib files with view controllers but when I run the app the width of the view controllers is smaller than normal :

[image: Screenshot]

I don't understand as it is set identically as with the xib files. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController0")

    self.addChildViewController(vc0!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0!.view)
    vc0!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1")

    var frame1 = vc1!.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1!.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1!.view)
    vc1!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2")

    var frame2 = vc2!.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2!.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2!.view)
    vc2!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3")

    var frame3 = vc3!.view.frame
    frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
    vc3!.view.frame = frame3

    self.addChildViewController(vc3!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc3!.view)
    vc3!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: You can try use .bounds instead of frame and add to the subview in the following method. Take a look because this method is called when the UI change: `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }`

Comment: When I wrote "add to the subview" I meant to move your code to the method added in the previous comment

Comment: It actually resized the view so it fits well but now the ViewController3 appears first and I can swipe right to ViewController2 and that's all...

Comment: Could you add the changes that you did in your code?

Comment: I added the above function as you said and replaced all the .frame by .bounds, do you want me to edit the post? The code doesn't fit in a comment.

Comment: Don't set the frame sizes in viewDidLoad, the screen sizes are not known at that point in time. Either add proper constraints in viewDidLoad, or set the frame size manually in layoutSubViews. But start by reading a good Cocoa book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that using viewDidLoad for set frame manually is a bit risky and should be avoided since the bounds are not set. Instead use the viewDidLayoutSubviews to do that but take a look because the method is called all the time when the UI elements change including constraints.

```
    var scrollViewAdded = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !scrollViewAdded {

        self.loadSrollView()

        self.scrollViewAdded = true
    }
}


func loadSrollView() {

    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

    let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController0")

    self.addChildViewController(vc0!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0!.view)
    vc0!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1")

    var frame1 = vc1!.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1!.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1!.view)
    vc1!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2")

    var frame2 = vc2!.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2!.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2!.view)
    vc2!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3")

    var frame3 = vc3!.view.frame
    frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
    vc3!.view.frame = frame3

    self.addChildViewController(vc3!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc3!.view)
    vc3!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)
}
```

Comment: Working well, thanks! Just a small detail : there is like a small blue border around the view as if there was a background, it's very very small but do you have an idea of how to remove it?

Comment: Sorry, I added a border to check if the views fit well. Remove the lines: `vc0?.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    vc0?.view.layer.borderWidth = 1`  do the same with vc1,vc2 and vc3

Comment: Thanks ! (should have seen it before asking you... sorry)